# Error by installing of slime for the chicken scheme

Tags: slime, chicken-scheme

After many lines of standard output text of `chicken-install slime` finally it has printed:

```
/usr/bin/csi -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)"\
 -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"synch\" \"2.1.2\"))" /tmp/temp8317.14272/synch/synch.setup

Error: (open-input-file) cannot open file - No such file or directory: "setup-helper"
```

Chicken version is 4.8.0.3.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Slime, chicken... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhyi0O01ys8

Comment: @Denis lol,chicken is a scheme implementation ;) slime is way to connect your editor to the lisp interpreter ;) (but everybody knows that KFC uses chicken slime 2.9.0)

Comment: I figured, lol, but the question's title is absolutely epic. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because that I had changed my chicken install path by setting the CHICKEN_REPOSITORY variable. The couse of this problem in that that installed files aren't available for loading by csi for making dependent eggs. Therefore solution of this problem is in setting the CHICKEN_INCLUDE_PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem. I changed CHICKEN_INCLUDE_PATH pointing it to the same path as CHICKEN_REPOSITORY and it worked!